# Change colour of money formatted cell to red if negative

Tags: tabulator

I have a column which is formatted using the  built in money formatter. I would like to change the text of the cell to red if the numeric value of the cell is negative.  I can't create a custom formatter because the column `formatter` option is already set to money.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a custom formatter, Mimic the money formatter in this code. I can't think of anything else

```js
let tabledata = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Oli ",
    money: 1,
    col: "red",
    dob: ""
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Mary ",
    money: -1,
    col: "blue",
    dob: "14/05/1982"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Christine ",
    money: 0,
    col: "green",
    dob: "22/05/1982"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Brendon ",
    money: 10,
    col: "orange",
    dob: "01/08/1980"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Margret ",
    money: -10,
    col: "yellow",
    dob: "31/01/1999"
  },
];

for (let i = 0; i < tabledata.length; i++) {

  if (tabledata[i].money < 0) {
    tabledata[i].money = "<span class='red'>$" +
      tabledata[i].money +
      "</span>"
  } else {
    tabledata[i].money = '$' + tabledata[i].money;
  }
}

const table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
  data: tabledata,
  layout: "fitColumns",
  columns: [{
      title: "id",
      field: "id"
    },
    {
      title: "name",
      field: "name"
    },
    {
      title: "money",
      field: "money",
      formatter: "html"
    },
    {
      title: "col",
      field: "col"
    },
    {
      title: "dob",
      field: "dob"
    },
  ]
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.4/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.4/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<body>
  <div id="example-table"></div>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I created an extra column in the end with a custom formatter function that output 'DR' to the cell if the row's running total was negative (in the same manner that bank statements show an overdrawn balance).  I'll add a feature request on the GitHub issues page.

Comment: In a roundabout way yes, if the money formatter had options to display negative balances in red or surrounded by parenthesis (an accounting convention), or with the letters 'DR' after the amount (bank statements) then that would be better.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution for this problem:

```
formatter:function(cell,params,callback) {
    let money = cell.getTable().modules.format.getFormatter("money");
    cell.getElement().style...
    return money(cell,params,callback);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/baumrock/vxpbhLsg/14/